StoredProcedureQuery with Oracle Type fails
Please help. I am not able to call oracle procedure which has Oracle type as input. Also share if any sample available in git. Thanks in advance.
Oracle Type:
create or replace TYPE STUDENT_ID_ARRAY AS TABLE OF NUMBER;

Oracle Proc:
create or replace NONEDITIONABLE PACKAGE student_pkg AS
    -- Define RefCursor type for returning cursors from procedures
    TYPE RefCursor IS REF CURSOR;

    PROCEDURE GetStudentInfo(p_department_id IN department.id%TYPE, p_student_ids IN STUDENT_ID_ARRAY, p_student_info OUT RefCursor);
END student_pkg;

create or replace NONEDITIONABLE PACKAGE BODY student_pkg AS

    -- Implementation of the GetStudentInfo procedure
    PROCEDURE GetStudentInfo(p_department_id IN department.id%TYPE, p_student_ids IN STUDENT_ID_ARRAY, p_student_info OUT RefCursor)
    IS
    BEGIN
        -- Call the existing procedure to get student details by department
        OPEN p_student_info FOR
            SELECT s.name AS student_name, d.name as  department_name
            FROM student s
            INNER JOIN department d ON s.department_id = d.id
            WHERE d.id = p_department_id
            AND s.id in (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE(p_student_ids));
    END GetStudentInfo;
END student_pkg;

Spring Data JPA Repository:
@Repository
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class TypeRepositoryImpl implements TypeRepository {

    private final EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public List<Object[]> getStudentInfo(int departmentId, List<Integer> studentIds) {
        StoredProcedureQuery query = entityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery("student_pkg.GetStudentInfo");

        // Set parameters
        query.registerStoredProcedureParameter("p_department_id", Integer.class, ParameterMode.IN);
        query.registerStoredProcedureParameter("p_student_ids", Object.class, ParameterMode.IN);
        query.registerStoredProcedureParameter("p_student_info", void.class, ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR);

        query.setParameter("p_department_id", departmentId);
        query.setParameter("p_student_ids", studentIds);
        
        query.execute();
        return query.getResultList();
    }

Getting Below Error:
2024-05-30T06:32:42.166+05:30  INFO 24604 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2024-05-30T06:32:42.167+05:30  INFO 24604 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 1 ms
2024-05-30T06:32:42.249+05:30 DEBUG 24604 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : 
    {call student_pkg.GetStudentInfo(?, ?, ?)}
Hibernate: 
    {call student_pkg.GetStudentInfo(?, ?, ?)}
2024-05-30T06:32:42.385+05:30  WARN 24604 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 6550, SQLState: 65000
2024-05-30T06:32:42.385+05:30 ERROR 24604 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'GETSTUDENTINFO'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

https://docs.oracle.com/error-help/db/ora-06550/
2024-05-30T06:32:42.396+05:30 ERROR 24604 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: Error calling CallableStatement.getMoreResults [ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'GETSTUDENTINFO'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored


Have you ever try origin number type not Java number type which is provide by  ojdbc?

@Peng Thanks for the reply can you elaborate what do you mean by origin number type ? Also provide any reference for the same.

Java's JDBC doesn't directly support Oracle's custom types. You need to use Oracle-specific classes from the oracle.jdbc package.
  @Override
    public List<Object[]> getStudentInfo(int departmentId, List<Integer> studentIds) throws SQLException {
        // Obtain Oracle connection
        Connection connection = entityManager.unwrap(Connection.class);
        OracleConnection oracleConnection = connection.unwrap(OracleConnection.class);

        // Convert List<Integer> to java.sql.Array
        Integer[] studentIdsArray = studentIds.toArray(new Integer[0]);
        Array oracleArray = oracleConnection.createOracleArray("STUDENT_ID_ARRAY", studentIdsArray);

        // Create stored procedure query
        StoredProcedureQuery query = entityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery("student_pkg.GetStudentInfo");

        // Set parameters
        query.registerStoredProcedureParameter("p_department_id", Integer.class, ParameterMode.IN);
        query.registerStoredProcedureParameter("p_student_ids", Array.class, ParameterMode.IN);
        query.registerStoredProcedureParameter("p_student_info", void.class, ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR);

        query.setParameter("p_department_id", departmentId);
        query.setParameter("p_student_ids", oracleArray);

        query.execute();

        return query.getResultList();
    }

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
    <version>19.8.0.0</version>
</dependency>

Reference
[1] Oracle JDBC

I will check and reply back

Try to declare your input array as:
TYPE STUDENT_ID_ARRAY AS TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;

But main part is your code is using ORM Hibernate to call specific PL/SQL procedure.
In the ORM concept you should beware of such code. It is not portable. Better to use a regular SELECT than a procedure call.
Otherwise, you are simply wasting resources using Hibernate or other ORMs, instead of direct work through the driver is much faster and using less memory.

Thanks but in my case it is legacy I have to handle.
